# How to transition to a UINavigationController from a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to transition (modal) via segue to a `UINavigationController` from a `UIViewController`.
My `UIViewController` and`UINavigationController` are in interface builder.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNavController", sender: self)
}
```

However it keeps giving me a warning: 
`Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x14d5095e0> on <Test.ViewController: 0x14d60d9d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `prepareForSegue`.  `prepareForSegue` is called once a segue has been triggered, so you don't need to trigger it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` inside `prepareForSegue`?
That is what is causing the error. You don't have to call the `performSegueWithIdentifier` again.

`performSegueWithIdentifier` is used to perform a segue operation. `prepareForSegue` is called after you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` function and before the segue transition happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a root view relationship for your Navigation Controller, otherwise it has nothing to display.

> A navigation controller is a container view controller—that is, it
>   embeds the content of other view controllers inside of itself.
>
> Every navigation stack must have at least one view controller to act
>   as the root.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html